# Probability of drawing two balls of certain color

Tags: probability

We have an urn with $8$ white balls, $4$ black balls and $2$ orange balls.

Pick two balls at random without replacement. If we want the event $E$ to be that we picked either (white, black) or (black,white). whats probability of this event?

By the inclusion exclusion formula we have

$$ P(E) = P(white,black) + P(black,white) + P( (w,b) \cap (b,w) )$$

So, P(white,black) is

$$ \frac{  8}{14} \cdot \frac{ 4}{13} $$

and $P(b,w) = \frac{ 4}{14} \frac{8}{13}$

$P( (w,b) \cap (b,w) )$ better be $0$ since it imposibble to have at the same time white and blacks and blacks and whites, but Im still a little confused as to why this is so. is my approach correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct, and your calculations are almost correct (the probability of $P(E)$ should've had $-P( (w,b) \cap (b,w) )$ instead). Right now I can't think of a reason why $P( (w,b) \cap (b,w) )$ is $0$ except "well clearly this is impossible so the probability must be $0$", though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hypergeometric formula to find the probability and that is

Required probability $= \dfrac{{8\choose 1}{4\choose 1}}{{14\choose 2}}$

gets you the same answer.